# Append div in labels as helper text. With in each radio group and its wrapper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/praveendubbaka/qoemfwgr/27/)

I want to append a div in labels as helper text. within each radio group and its wrapper div.

I have a radio buttons group code generated dynamically, so I can't add static helper text to labels using HTML.

I am placing div under radio group div and adding div with helper text and wrapping each radio group with another div, then using append. I am adding its only helper text div to its labels using classes.

before  screen [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rYTU.png)

After screen  [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tXDp.png)

```
<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>

</div>

<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No</label>
   </span>
</div>
    <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText3">Not sure</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
<div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3">not sure helper text</div>

</div>
```

I want to Append Yes helper text into  Yes  using jQuery like this but my script is adding multiple/duplicate divs:

`````
   $("div.helperTextWrapper ").each(function(index) {

  $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText1');
   $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText2');
    $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText3');

    });


<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes
           <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

</div>




<div class="helperTextWrapper" >

<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText1">Yes
           <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1">Yes helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText2">No
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2">no helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
    <div>
    <span>
       <label class="RadioButtonHelperText3">Not sure
        <div class="RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3">not sure helper text</div>
        </label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>

</div>

````
`````

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.radioTable").each(function() {
  $(this).parents(".helperTextWrapper").each(function(index) {
   $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText1');
   $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText2');
    $(this).find('.RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3').appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText3');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel1 ").each(function() {

  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText1');

    });

        $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel2 ").each(function() {

  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText2');

    });

            $(".RadioButtonHelperTextLabel3 ").each(function() {

  $(this).appendTo('.RadioButtonHelperText3');

    });
    ```
````